# how to enter ' = c+ac ' into a cell in excel when c is a protected letter

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet where I am defining formulas in cells including the protected letter c. Changing c to _c has worked just fine until I entered =_c+a_c. I don't want to change letter c to something else for clarity.

A typical column looks like l, a, b, ab, c, ac, ab, abc. Calculation column looks like l+a, b+ab, c+ac, bc+abc, a-l, ab-b, ac-c, abc-bc. I had to change (1) to l to make the calculations run.

I ran into trouble with _c+a_c. It does not like a_c. How I can do this?

Comment: Multiplication in Excel has to use the `*` operator. So your formula will have to use the format `=_c+a*_c`.

Comment: ac is a variable like x or y. It just contains two letters.

Comment: I was confused because changing `c` to `_c` in two places implied that that it was the same variable. If I create a defined cell as `_c` and another cell defined as `ac`, the formula `=_c+ac` works fine. Likewise if I define another cell as `a_c` then change the formula to `=_c+a_c`, that also works fine. I'm thinking the issue is with your defined names. The name `c` is an Excel reserved name, but `ac` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, c needs to be entered as _c but anything else involving c such as ac is ok as is. c and r are protected variables in excel. I'd like to put in a good word here for Scott Felton of INR2 of Denver Colorado.